# Spring Cloud Sleuth with OpenTracing

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth, opentracing

Is there a way to use Spring Cloud Sleuth with OpenTracing? I want to connect Spring clients with Jaeger

Comment: You may want to try asking at https://gitter.im/spring-cloud/spring-cloud

Comment: Also, Jaeger now has an HTTP endpoint that can receive spans in Zipkin Thrift format. But because Sleuth is not supporting OpenTracing, you cannot actually use Jaeger Java client with it, so will be missing many of the features it provides, like adaptive sampling.

Comment: @Javier You got any solutions for this problem?

Comment: Not really, But now I just change the strategy and use what Spring had built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an ongoing discussion over here - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/599 . In general we don't explicitly use the OpenTracing API but we are Zipkin compatible in terms of header propagation. You can also manipulate the header names as you wish so if any sort of library you're using requires other header names for span / trace etc. then you can set it yourself as you want to.

Answer (score 16):

Spring Sleuth is now OpenTracing compatible. All you have to do is use OpenTracing Jars in your class path.

You can then use Sleuth-Zipkin to send instrumentation data to Jaeger's Zipkin collector.

This way you achieve everything you want with minimal configuration.

You can use my sample program as an example here:

https://github.com/anoophp777/spring-webflux-jaegar-log4j2